# Android SensorManager registerListener - not possible to set custom interval of sensor events

Tags: android-sensors

I wanted to set an individual interval of sensor events beside:

the given delays: "SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_U, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, ENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST".

But non of the "registerListener" methodes seems to support an individual value: [image: every methode need "rateUS"]
Looking into the implementation of the SensorManager class shows:

```
public boolean registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rateUs,
        int maxBatchReportLatencyUs) {
        int delay = getDelay(rateUs);
        return registerListenerImpl(listener, sensor, delay, null,maxBatchReportLatencyUs, 0);
    }


    private static int getDelay(int rate) {
        int delay = -1;
        switch (rate) {
            case SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST:
                delay = 0;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_GAME:
                delay = 20000;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_UI:
                delay = 66667;
                break;
            case SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL:
                delay = 200000;
                break;
            default:
                delay = rate;
                break;
        }
        return delay;
    }
```

Is there realy no way to set an individual value for the sensor event interval?

Answer (score 1):

SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, etc are all simply integers, as shown in your code. Saying you want SENSOR_DELAY_UI is the same as telling the sensor manager to use an interval of 66667 microseconds. However, per the docs, you can simply input your own interval in that field:

> The desired delay between two consecutive events in microseconds. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. Can be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST **or the delay in microseconds.**

However, it's important to note the other part of that quote:

> ...The desired delay between two consecutive events in microseconds. **This is only a hint to the system.**...

At the end of the day, it's just a suggestion and the Android system doesn't seem to be too good about respecting your request. If you really care about the interval I would suggest adding a method in your callback that checks the time delta between now and the last time you recorded a sensor value and then only recording it if its been sufficiently long.

Source: [Android Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `Timer` and a `boolean` flag to handle this problem:
imagine you want to check sensor event values every 1 seconds(for example):

```
boolean mustReadSensor;
Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {           
         mustReadSensor = true;       
     }
 }, 0, 1000);  // 1000 ms delay
```

and here is `onSensorChanged`:

```
 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
   if (!mustReadSensor) {
        return;
    }
     mustReadSensor = false;
     //handle sensor values here
}
```